# Из массива в БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть задача перенести данные из одной БД во вторую на другом сервере. Таблицы идентичной структуры. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так в коде, ибо он не вставляет данные в БД.

```
$query="SELECT r1, r2, r3, r4 FROM DB1.TB1"; 
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result(r1, r2, r3, r4);  $sql = array();//помещаю в массив, так как БД на разных серверах
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $r1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($r1);
    ...
    $r4 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($r4);
    $sql[] = "('$r1','$r2', '$r3', '$r4')";
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Подключение ко второй БД

```
if(count($sql) > 0) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO DB2.TB2 VALUES "
        . implode(',', $sql) .
        " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        r1= VALUES(r1),
        ...
        r4= VALUES(r4)";
  $mysqli->query($query);
}
$mysqli->close();
```

PS. Некоторые значения могут быть пустыми.
Ошибки нет никакой при выполнении скрипта :(
`Commit` не делаю. По умолчанию MySQL работает в режиме autocommit.
Дамп не рассматривал. Цель - автоматически раз в месяц обновлять таблицу Cron`ом. Нужны не все данные. В таблице около 100, мне нужно около 30 столбцов.

Comment: Мало кода для анализа. Вы лучше скажите, что значит _не вставляет данные в БД_? Пишет ошибку, какую? Ничего не пишет?

Comment: Commit сделать не забываешь?

Comment: Спрошу глупость: а чем `mysqldump` не угодил?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Твой подход полезен только если есть задача решить именно так. ВО всех остальных случаях надо такого избегать.

1.Самый просто способ сдампить базу

```
mysqldump -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db1 | mysql -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db2
```

2.Скопировать таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE x LIKE y;
```

3. Скопировать таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE x LIKE other_db.y;
```

4. Еще

```
INSERT INTO x SELECT * FROM other_db.y;
```

5. Еще способ

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl [AS] SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
```

6. Хардкор, зайти на удаленную машину , сделать дам , скопировать на свою машину, залить дамп.

```
#Конектимся к кдаленной машине , создаем и сохраняем дамп
ssh user@192.168.1.5 <<'ENDSSH'
mysqldump --skip-triggers -p'pass' -uuser db_name > /home/user/dump.sql
ENDSSH

#копируем дамп на свою машину
rsync -zvru -P user@192.168.1.5:/home/user/dump.sql /home/user1/copy.dump.sql
#разворачиваем дамп
mysql -p'pass1' -uuser1 dbname1 < /home/user1/copy.dump.sql
```

Все эти способы более подходящие нежели вручную парсить sql

Comment: Я так понимаю, что мне подойдет именно дамп,  так как селекты и криэйты подойдет для работы с одной БД, а мне нужны 2 на разных серверах?

Comment: Да именно так , первый вариант самый эффективный для этого